# Xamarin how to release GPS service

Tags: xamarin

I have written an app that query the Gps coordinates once off. My problem is that sometimes the app does not release the GPS service. The GPS icon stays on the screen forever. What could be the possible cause ? Here is my code below :

```
string latitude = string.Empty;
string longitude = string.Empty;
string Area = string.Empty;
Geocoder geoCoder = null;
IGeolocator locator = null;

try
{
    //get gps
    string myGps = string.Empty;
    locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
    locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

    TimeSpan sp = new TimeSpan(10000);

    var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(sp);

    latitude = position.Latitude.ToString();
    longitude = position.Longitude.ToString();

    geoCoder = new Geocoder(this.ApplicationContext);

    var addresses = geoCoder.GetFromLocation(position.Latitude, position.Longitude, 1);

   if (addresses != null)
                        Area = addresses[0].CountryName + ", " + addresses[0].Locality + ", " + addresses[0].SubLocality + ", " + addresses[0].FeatureName;

                    successful = true;
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try first if your GPS is enabled.

Try that:

```
        if (CrossGeolocator.Current.IsGeolocationEnabled)
            GeoLoc = await CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

or even something like that :

```
        if (CrossGeolocator.IsSupported && CrossGeolocator.Current.IsGeolocationAvailable && CrossGeolocator.Current.IsGeolocationEnabled)
            GeoLoc = await CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

Comment: i have tried your solution. I'm still experiencing the issue.

Comment: Ok, did you try to let the timeout  to 10 seconds and put all your code in a try catch block ?

If something goes wrong you should get an Exception and maybe that will help to understand what haopen.

Comment: Yes, i put my code in a try catch. I'm not receiving any errors. Where can i set the timeout ? On which object ?

Comment: It's the parameter in **CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync(X)**

Comment: Yes, i did mention the timeout in my code. This line represent the time out : TimeSpan sp = new TimeSpan(10000); .